# Error > Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080 > While connecting the Visual Code using code-server

Tags: visual-studio, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, xcode-server

Trying to install Visual Code IDE in VM Instance. After running the code-server, while checking view on browser, it is giving an error.
Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080.
Ensure your server is listening on port 8080 and try again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grzi7.png)

reference link to install VS Code in GCC:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-run-visual-studio-code-in-google-cloud-shell-354d125d5748

Comment: Your code is listening on `localhost`. This means that you cannot access the program from outside Cloud Shell. You can verify that your program is running by opening another Cloud Shell tab and running `curl -i http://localhost:8080/` You will see the output of your program. `localhost` is the loopback device. To fix the problem, change the listening port from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try openning on your browser:
http://[your-external-ip]:8080/

Its important to change the default "https" to "http".

I also added the port 8080 on my firewall permisions on gcp.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your host to `0.0.0.0`. When you start the server, your command could be like this:

```
./code-server --no-auth --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0
```

And everything should work fine. Try it :D

Comment: I tried running with the above mentioned command. still it's not working "Preview on Port 8080" - it's giving an error "400(Not Found)!! The requested URL was not found on this server"

Comment: You tried to use `https://8080-dot-YOURID-dot-devshell.appspot.com/login` as the tutorial you're using suggests?