# Code server (Visual Studio Code) on Google Cloud Engine - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform

I want to set up a google cloud engine machine with VSCode installed. 
I have followed this installation:https://fireship.io/lessons/vscode-cloud-coder-tensorflow/
1. ubuntu 20 LTS
2. wget https://github.com/codercom/code-server/releases/download/{version}/code-server-{version}-linux-x64.tar.gz
3. tar -xvzf code-server-{version}-linux-x64.tar.gz
4. cd code-server-{version}-linux-x64
5. sudo ./code-server -p 80

output is:
[image: server-code call]

The firewall rules are:
[image: Firewall rules]

when I browse to http://EXTERNAL_IP:80
[image: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

What is the missing to makke sure that the port is open and accessible on the server side?

Thanks,
eilalan

Comment: are the firewall rules applied to the "server-code-bazel-1" instance?

Comment: for my case, yes it's but still can't reach out to my vscode.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a way for me. According to an answer here: [Error > Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080 > While connecting the Visual Code using code-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093373/error-could-not-connect-to-cloud-shell-on-port-8080-while-connecting-the-vis)

You need to run code-server under `--host 0.0.0.0`

i.e. `$ PASSWORD=password PORT=8443 code-server --host 0.0.0.0`